# Proof Verification for Discrete Math Class

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, proof-verification

Prove that $n^2$ is even iff $n$ is even.

I proved it like this:

Case I: $n$ is even

1) $n = 2a$  $(a\in Z)$

2) $n^2 = 4a^2 = 2(2a^2)$

3) $2a^2 = K$ $(K \in Z)$

4) $n^2 = 2K$

Case II: $n$ is odd

1) $n = 2a + 1$ $(a\in Z)$

2)$n^2 = 4a^2 + 4a +1 = 2(2a^2 + 2a) + 1$

3) $2a^2 + 2a = K$ $K\in Z$

4) $n^2 = 2K+1$

My book does it slightly differently:
[image]

Is my proof still correct?

Comment: A LaTeX suggestion: use `\in` for the symbol $\in$, rather than `\epsilon`, which gives $\epsilon$.

Comment: Your proof is almost identical to the book, you have just written it in your own order and in your own words. Looks good to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to prove $A \iff B$.

Your book proves $A \Rightarrow B$ and $B \Rightarrow A$.

You prove $A \Rightarrow B$ and $\lnot A \Rightarrow \lnot B$. However, $\lnot A \Rightarrow \lnot B$ is logically equivalent to $B \Rightarrow A$.

All of these things can be checked with truth tables.  For example:

$\begin{array} {|cc|cc|}
A & B & B \Rightarrow A & \lnot A \Rightarrow \lnot B \\ \hline
\text{T} & \text{T} & \text{T} & \text{T} \\ \hline
\text{T} & \text{F} & \text{T} & \text{T} \\ \hline
\text{F} & \text{T} & \text{F} & \text{F} \\ \hline
\text{F} & \text{F} & \text{T} & \text{T} \\ \hline
\end{array}$

$\begin{array} {|cc|cc|c|c|}
A & B & A \Rightarrow B & B \Rightarrow \lnot A & (A \Rightarrow B) \text{ and } (B \Rightarrow A) & A \text{ iff } B\\ \hline
\text{T} & \text{T} & \text{T} & \text{T} & \text{T} & \text{T} \\ \hline
\text{T} & \text{F} & \text{F} & \text{T} & \text{F} & \text{F} \\ \hline
\text{F} & \text{T} & \text{T} & \text{F} & \text{F} & \text{F} \\ \hline
\text{F} & \text{F} & \text{T} & \text{T} & \text{T} & \text{T} \\ \hline
\end{array}$